# Is my object being overwritten and disposed

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

using Javascript.

I declare an image variable like so:

```
var myIMG = new Image();
```

I load up 100 images like this:

```
for (var test =0 ; test < 100; test++)
{
     myIMG.src = null;
     myIMG.src = {get new image from server somehow}
}
```

and this:

```
for (var test =0 ; test < 100; test++)
{
     myIMG = new Image();
     myIMG.src = {get new image from server somehow}
     myIMG.src = null;
     delete myIMG
}
```

(code is for testing purposes)

What is the correct way to reduce memory consumption?

Thanks

Comment: well you probably need to give time for the image to load...

Comment: Hi, it was supposed to be a test 'harness'. This is not production code. I was just looking at the principle. But thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested to know that JavaScript doesn't have a local scope for a `for` loop. It's scoping is based on functions. Hence, you should not redeclare `var myImg` more than once in a function.

Going back to your code, I would suggest that you only declare one `new Image()` (i.e. outside the loop), which should be more efficient

```
var i, myImg = new Image();

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    myImg.src = getNewSource();
}
```

The `delete` property is meant for removing an item from an object. For example:

```
var myObj = { a: 2, b: 3 };
delete myObj.a;
// myObj will now be { b: 3 }
```

However, this does not necessary release the memory, but the reference to the item in the object. The memory is claimed back by the JavaScript garbage collector (and you cannot trigger this in your code)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi, I did look at garbage collector and using static memory for pre-allocation of memory and decided to leave alone.  I really wanted to kno whether img.src = null and then reassigning is better (or not) than overwriting or re-declaring the variable. Thanks for that titbit about 'var' -bad code on my part and I will edit. Thanks

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I wouldn't have though `img.src = null` would make it better. That would still be changing the reference and not automatically removing `src` property. It would be up to the garbage collector to recognise that old value no longer has any references to it and recycle it. You'll find that the different implementations of JavaScript do this differently and at different intervals

Comment: HI, that is exactly what I concluded as well. Thanks